# What's wrong with my way of checking that a number is a multiple of another number?

Tags: delphi, modulo

I am using this code in a procedure and I am having troubles with the 1st if clause:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,indice,n,conto:integer;
    a:string;
begin
  indice:=1;
  conto:=0;

  Memo2.Lines.Add('<tr>');

  for i := 1 to 649 do
   begin
    if ((i <> 11) or (i mod 11 <> 0)) then
     begin
      proced4();
     end
    else
     begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add('</tr><tr>');
      proced5();
    end;
   end;
end;
```

I have a for that goes from 1 to 649. When the index is a multiple of 11 `11, 22, 33, 44...` I must call

```
Memo2.Lines.Add('</tr><tr>');
proced5();
```

With the code I wrote, only when the index i is 11 the code calls proced5(). But, for example, when the i is 22 or 33 it executes proced4() instead of proced5().

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ok but this haven't solved my problem.

Comment: What do you need to fix?

Comment: With the code I wrote, only when the index i is 11 the code calls `proced5()`. But, for example, when the i is 22 or 33 it executes `proced4()` instead of `proced5()`.

Comment: `if (i mod 11 = 0) then begin Memo2.Lines.Add('</tr><tr>'); proced5(); end else proced4();` Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Why did you ask the question in a comment? When you ask us to fix something, you have to tell us: 1. What you expect to happen, 2. What does happen.  Remember that we cannot read your mind.  Please do put that information into the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Alberto did say that in his question, it was just a bit cryptic that's all, see his first draft, second to last line.

Comment: If I were you I'd invest some time to refactor this code. Start by eliminating all compiler warnings, and keep it clean. Next, make sure to place this code in a separate method at least. Get rid of magic constants. Don't use gui elements to store your data (memo2 here), but creat your own tstringlist and append it to memo2 when you're done. You'll see that it becomes easier to add complexity and to maintain your code when you do those refactorings.

Comment: As for why the original code wasn't working as expected...  It should be `and` instead of `or`.  `if ((i <> 11) AND (i mod 11 <> 0)) then`. Though, as already pointed out, `i <> 11` isn't necessary as it is taken care of by `(i mod 11 <> 0)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The if test does not make sense:

```
i mod 11 <<-- will be 0 for any multiple of 11. (including 0) 
(i <> 11)  <<-- superflous, the mod already does the job.
```

Also for sanity it is best to always have your if to test for something positive.
Humans are bad at parsing negations.

```
  for i := 1 to 649 do begin
    if ((i mod 11) = 0) then begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add('</tr><tr>');
      procedureWithAMeaningfulName5();
    end else {if not multiple of 11 then} begin
      procedureWithAMeaningfulName4();
    end;
  end; {for}
```

**Comments on coding style**
Function and variable names should indicate their meaning.

```
`Button1`: bad, what does the button do? Should e.g. `ButtonBuildHTMLTable`  
`proced5`: what the hell does that do?? Give it a meaningful name.  
`indice`: Index of what?
`conto`: count of what?
```

Your indentation is inconsistent; did you know that pressing <kbd>CTRL + D</kbd> will make Delphi auto-indent your code for you?

**Why does your code not work**

Let's pick apart the test.

```
if ((i <> 11) or (i mod 11 <> 0)) then
```

1. The `or` returns `true` if either (i <> 11) is true or (i mod 11 <> 0) is true.
2. (i <> 11) is almost always true, except when i = 11.
3. Therefore test B:`(i mod 11 <> 0)` only ever gets tested if (i = 11).
4. In all other cases `proced4();` gets run.
5. cases i=22, i=33 etc do not meet the test `not(i <> 11)` aka `(i = 11)` and therefore do not trigger the else.
6. Notice the double negation in point 5, this is why if statements should test something positive.

Comment: I don't think Ctrl+D work on older versions. Was it D2010 AitoIndent was introduced ?